# Loop through results and aggregate and spit out php

Tags: php, loops

**What I'm trying to accomplish with my code below:** it performs the `SELECT`, which should return (2) results, those results pulling ~10 items each (total items: ~20) and display those on the page.

**What actually happens:** It pulls the second result, thus outputting only ~10 results out of a possible 20. So, the `$result` var should really have a total of ~20 items after looping... but it only has 10.. I've tested the actual output and the query...

Any thoughts?

```
<?php

## Loop through results from mysql
try{
    #connection string
        // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thdb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thdb','user','pass',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
        $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1");
    #call stored proc
        $q->execute();
    #get the rows into an array
        $result = $q->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $r){
            $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
            $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
            # -> Setup XML
            $newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
        }   

    # -----> Load News Stories
        for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

    # Source of Article Info-->
            $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

    # Actual News Article Info -->
            $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
            $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;

    # Output Results ------------>      
            echo '<hr>';
            echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
            //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
            echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
            echo '<hr>';
        }
} // try

catch(Exception $e){

    $errorStored = $e->getMessage() . ' on ' .'/errors/fanwire_loop.php';  #where errors are stored
    $pageDateOfError = '/aggregate_looping.php'.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); #inc the file and date into the file too
    file_put_contents($errorStored,$pageDateOfError, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
} // catch

?>
```

**** Edited `try{}`

```
# Only outputs (2) `items`
    try{
        #connection string
            // $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thdb',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $dbconn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=thdb','user','pass',array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
            $q = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT FW_ArtSrcLink FROM FW_ArtSrc WHERE OneSet=1");
        #call stored proc
            $q->execute();
        #get the rows into an array
            $result = $q->fetchAll();
            $newsStory = array();
            foreach($result as $r){
                $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
                $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
                # -> Setup XML
                $newsStory[] = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
            }   

        # -----> Load News Stories
            for($i = 0;$i<sizeof($newsStory); $i++){

        # Source of Article Info-->
                $SrcTitle=$newsStory[$i]->title;
                $SrcLink=$newsStory[$i]->link;

        # Actual News Article Info -->
                $title=$newsStory[$i]->title;
                $desc=$newsStory[$i]->description;

        # Output Results ------------>      
                echo '<hr>';
                echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
                //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
                echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
                echo '<hr>';
            }
    } // try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($result as $r){
  $xmlUrl = $r['FW_ArtSrcLink'];
  $ConvertToXml = simplexml_load_file($xmlUrl);
  # -> Setup XML
  $newsStory = $ConvertToXml->channel->item;
}
```

You did destructive assignment to `$newsStory` here, I assume it's an array so use `$newsStory[] = ...` instead.

Comment: @LeleDumbo - I've edited my code above... but it only outputs two items, not 10 anymore... What am I doing wrong? should be outputting ~20 :/

Comment: what's the output of `count($result)`?

Comment: If I do:  # Output Results ------------>  
   echo '<hr>';
   echo '<strong>'.'Title:'.$title.'</strong>'.'(via: <a href=\''.$SrcLink.'\'>'.$SrcTitle.'</a>'.'<br />';
   //echo 'Link:'.$link.'<br />';
   echo 'Description'.$desc.'<br>';
   echo 'count '.count($result);
   echo '<hr>';

Comment: the query returns two rows then, not 10 or 20